# Showing messages from sub-folders in parent-folder with Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have some structure of `Local Folders` in `Mozilla Thunderbird`:

```
Local Folders
--Clients
----Client 1
----Client 2
```

And I've set the `Message Filters` so mails wents either to `Clients/Client 1` or `Clients/Client 2`.

When I choose `Client 1` I see some mails in it. Same with `Client 2` (everything's ok).

But when I switch to `Clients` I see nothing (which is correct, but not what I want).

**When I click on `Clients` I want to see messages from all of the sub-folders (`Client 1`, `Client 2`) as well. How to do it?**

I **do not want to copy all the messages** (imagine more sub-sub-sub folders and many copies of hundreds of mails..).

Comment: Exactly the behaviour I want too !! I'm looking for it for month.. +1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to achieve this is with a search. That is the only mechanism that will present emails across folders. This is because each folder is actually indexed in a separate file.

I would think - though I admit I've not tried - that you could come up with a search that would do what you want.